# Proof of an alternate form of the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, contest-math

[image]

Since it is all positive squaring does not change anything. So:

$$ (a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2) + 2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + \cdots b_n^2)} + (b_1^2 + \cdots + b_n^2) \ge (a_1 + b_1)^2 + \cdots + (a_n + b_n)^2   $$

The part inside the square root is clearly Cauchy's inequality so:

$$2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + \cdots b_n^2)} \ge 2(a_1b_1 + \cdots + a_nb_n)$$

I see the RHS is also in that form, but there is an issue.help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn

Comment: That does not help whatsoever...

Comment: I honestly don't see where you have a problem. Could you specify precisely what you are asking?

Comment: Try taking the sum of squares on the left to the right, and then expanding the squares on the right. Lots of things will cancel...

Comment: @Wojowu, how do I get to the RHS of the original inequality?

Comment: Got it, it was insanely easy.

Comment: This is Minkowski's inequality for $p=2$. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying as per my comment,
$$
(a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2) + 2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + ... b_n^2)} + (b_1^2 + ... + b_n^2) \ge (a_1 + b_1)^2 + ... + (a_n + b_n)^2 \\
\Rightarrow 2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + ... b_n^2)} \geq (a_1 + b_1)^2 + ... + (a_n + b_n)^2 - (a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2) - (b_1^2 + ... + b_n^2) \\
\Rightarrow 2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + ... b_n^2)} \geq 2a_1b_1 + ... + 2a_nb_n \\
\Rightarrow (a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2)(b_1^2 + ... b_n^2) \geq (a_1b_1 + ... + a_nb_n)^2
$$
which is nothing but Cauchy's inequality.